# When I use git add . command it keeps showing me warnings

Tags: git

The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/filter-items.js.

What will be the method to sort this problem out.

Comment: Most likely the remote project files were committed using Linux LF line endings.  You're running Windows, and so the line endings have been saved as CFLF.  The warning message you are seeing is about this.

Comment: git config --global core.autocrlf true (I used this command and it worked)